# How to sort a List of objects based on one variable using lambda expression?

Tags: java, list, sorting, lambda

I tried to use lambda expressions to sort the list of objects based on name in JDK 1.8. but it shows compilation error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Code:

```
    Train trains = new Train();
    trains.setName("Yerlin");
    trains.setCode("YYT");
    Train trains2 = new Train();
    trains2 .setName("Delhi");
    trains2 .setCode("DEH");
List<Train > traindetail= new ArrayList<Train >();
    traindetail.add(trains);
    traindetail.add(trains2);
    traindetail.stream().sorted(Train object1 , Train object2) -> object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName()));
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The problem in this code is wrong lambda syntax.

Comment: @LutzHorn a missing parenthesis. Then, it's a typo and should be closed as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OK, but for a different reason.

Comment: `traindetail.sort(Comparator.comparing(Train::getName));` would sort your list in-place. you don't need to seperate `stream`, unless you want to maintain seperate lists.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a paren:

```
airport.stream().sorted(Train object1 , Train object2) -> object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName()));
                        ^--here
```

However, you would be advised to use a much more concise syntax:

```
airport.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Train::getName));
```

Then there will be no parens to miss. With the Streams API usage we usally apply static imports liberally, so

```
airport.stream().sorted(comparing(Train::getName));
```

I see you don't assign the stream object and do not apply any terminal operations, so maybe you should be aware that the expression above has still taken no action on your data. You just declared that the stream will be sorted once you apply a terminal operation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.Because I thought lambda expressions won't need comparable interface and just a above statement will sufficient to sort.If not kindly explain more abt stream objects and terminal operation for the above

Comment: Are you meant  that i need to use collect(Collectors.toList() at the end of expression

Comment: The signature of the sorting method is `Stream#sorted(Comparator<T>)`---so yes, you do need that interface (there was no mention of `Comparable`, though). And yes, you need to collect to list, or print, or whatever makes sense to your use case.

Comment: Collectors.to list will assign in the existing list reference or it creates a new varibale?

Comment: The stream doesn't know or care that its source happens to be a list. The Collector will create a list of its own.

Comment: I am confused.If possible can you help me that what needs to be included in the above piece of code (which i posted) to return the sorted objects based on name

Comment: `List<Train> sorted = airport.stream().sorted(comparing(Train::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
//                      v add ( here
airport.stream().sorted((Train object1 , Train object2) ->
  object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName()));
```